# Not able to launch PyCharm on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pycharm

I downloaded the .tar.gz package and extracted it in a folder, now when I open pycharm.sh all it opens is a script in gedit. What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following from the terminal:

`sudo chmod +x pycharm.sh`

`./pycharm.sh`